# Convert Timestamp from PostgreSQL to Time Zone in Query (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Past the hours of head-banging for this one.

I am attempting to separate the query model from PG for the model start_time (stored in UTC) by day group.

- Morning (12a - 12p)
- Afternoon (12p - 5p)
- Evening (5p - 12a)

I've tried scope methods, queries by instance methods, and overall class methods. All of which return the day group by UTC (**not the local time zone for the scheduled event**)

```
# event.rb
def self.morning
  startday = 0
  midday = 12
  Event.where("extract(hour from start_time) >= ? AND extract(hour from start_time) < ?", startday, midday)
end
```

Also tried,

```
def self.afternoon
  midday = "12:00:00"
  eveday = "17:00:00"
  Event.where("start_time::time >= ? AND start_time::time < ?", midday, eveday)
end
```

When console prompting (and generally throughout the app) I call event.start_time is successfully returned in the local time zone (set in the application.rb file)

But unless called outside of the model, the start_time continues to query as UTC.

I do not want to preset the DB timezone (as this is bad practice and the app is used globally)

**Edit**

As an example in the view, I am calling

```
<% events.morning.order("start_time ASC").each do |fit_class| %>
...
```

where,

```
events = @events = Event.all # passed through a partial
```

Comment: I wrote a post on rails and timezones you might find useful: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ there is also old sample application code that goes with it and has various scenarios of how you might need to work with timezones.

Comment: @house9 solid article! Learned an enormous amount about querying via timezone. It leads to an even further hidden complexity in my investigation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012499/using-rails-where-on-class-method-custom-column-queries). I will post my better-practiced solution when discovered!

Comment: Have you tried querying with time zone formatted fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add scopes for Event model with time zone checks

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  scope :morning, -> { where(
    "start_time >= ? AND start_time < ?",
      formatted_time(0), formatted_time(12))
  }

  scope :afternoon, -> { where(
    "start_time >= ? AND start_time < ?",
      formatted_time(12), formatted_time(17))
  }

  scope :evening, -> { where(
    "start_time >= ? AND start_time < ?",
      formatted_time(17), formatted_time(24))
  }

  private

  def formatted_time(hour = 0)
    Time.zone.parse(Date.current.to_s).change(hour: hour)
  end
end
```

You don't have to modify any other time zone settings for this query. Hope it helps!

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For onlookers, my temporary solution is as follows (MUCH research into the PostgreSQL docs):

```
def self.morning
  startday = 0
  midday = 12
  Event.where("extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') >= ? AND extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') < ?", startday, midday)
end

def self.afternoon
  midday = 12
  eveday = 17
  Event.where("extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') >= ? AND extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') < ?", midday, eveday)
end

def self.evening
  eveday = 17
  endday = 24
  Event.where("extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') >= ? AND extract(hour from start_time - interval '6 hours') < ?", eveday, endday)
end
```

This required me to preset the application time zone.

```
# application.rb
config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

I will change post the full-solution update when discovered!